# Flexslider : To Display Next Button if More then 2 Items

Tags: flexslider

Flex slider Implementation :

Hello I have more then 2 Video thumbnails i want to display 2 thumbnails in beginning and then want arrow as next button to show third and all next until it reaches to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
`<div class="flexslider" style="width:50%">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <a>item1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>item2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>item3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>item4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>item5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>`

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshowSpeed: 2000,
            controlNav:false,
            itemWidth: 600,
            itemMargin: 5,
            animationLoop: true,
            directionNav: true,
            nextText: "Next",
            minItems: 2,
            move: 1
        });
    });
</script>`

It shows First Two items and next item on click of next button.